# how to display only emp_target column name using left join

Tags: sql

**Emp table:**
EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO

**emp_target table:**
TOTAL_NO_OF_EMPLOYEES  TOTAL_SAL HIGHEST_SAL LOWEST_SAL AVERGAE_SAL     DEPTNO

**Output should be :**
TOTAL_NO_OF_EMPLOYEES  TOTAL_SAL HIGHEST_SAL LOWEST_SAL AVERGAE_SAL     DEPTNO

**I tried:**

```
select count(empno) as Total_no_of_employees,sum(sal) as Total_sal,max(sal) as Highest_sal,
round(avg(sal)) as avergae_sal,min(sal) as lowest_sal
from emp
Left outer join emp_target  on emp.deptno = emp_target.deptno
where emp.deptno not in (select deptno from emp_target);
```

Comment: emp_target is your target table? Why do you join with a table that is supposed to be the result of your sql code?

Comment: what is the query to display only target table columns @gregor

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Comment: i need to display only target table column.what is the query @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

If your input data is the table EMP and your resulting table should be EMP_TARGET then the solution is as follows

```
create table EMP_TARGET as
select
   depno,
   count(empno) as Total_no_of_employees,
   sum(sal) as Total_sal,
   max(sal) as Highest_sal,
   round(avg(sal)) as average_sal,
   min(sal) as lowest_sal
from EMP
group by deptno
```

Comment: i need to display only emp_target table column names using left joins @gregor

Comment: So you already have a table EMP_TARGET and you want to update this table with data for Departments that are not yet included in your target table? Then you just have to insert the data from the step above. If I take your comment literally then the table EMP is not needed at all... if you just want to display column names (and no contents...?) of the target table? It would be helpful to show us some sample data for table EMP as well as data of the target table.